# Graphing a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector (in physic) designated asF1=250cos(60)i+250cos(60)j+250cos(45)k, and i would like to see it in a 3D graphic with the axis centered at the origin, after what i would include other vector from there. But i have been unable to graph it.
I would like it to look like this:

[image: Vector in Space]

(first time user, would appreciate as much info as possible)

Thanks in advance

Seb.

Comment: "Please help me,I've been able to do this ..." is highly preferred here to "Please, solve my problem". What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I @belisarius i`m sorry for asking wrongly.

Comment: I`ve tried Plot3D, Line, Vector...Plot3D[Line[{Cos[60], Cos[60], -Cos[45]}], {x, -20, 20}],Plot3D[(250 cos[60] + 250 cos[60] - 250 cos[45])*x, {x, -20, 20}], stuff like that but i know it`s not the good tipping, because i,j,k are not variable. but i can`t seem to find any good answer either here or on the Mathematica library, though it seem pretty simple and basic...

Comment: (i`m sorry for the layout to... )

Comment: @Artes Really similar, indeed

Comment: it is the same question (sorry for duplicating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {Cos[60], Cos[60], -Cos[45]}}], 
 PlotRange -> {#, #, #} &@{-1, 1}, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks enormously, i will be able to catch up from here. You are really helpful.

Comment: May i ask why you used {#,#,#}&@{-1,1}...what does it do, what does it stand for ?

Comment: @SebastienComtois Copy it to your notebook and evaluate it

Comment: There is something wrong, it`s not in the good quadrant... it is supposed to be in {+,+,-} not in {-,-,-}, how is it possible that a vector(arrow) of origin {0,0,0} and end point at { Cos[60], Cos[60], -Cos[45] } can end up in that orientation ?

Comment: and i`ve tried what you said but i don`t understand what the &@ ...(and everything else related to it), stands for.

Comment: it say >>The specified setting for the option Graphics3DBoxOptions, PlotRange cannot be used. >> if i change the ### value, for the {-1,1}, if i understand correctly, i think it`s for box orientation...size...???

Comment: @SebastienComtois Well, you need to spend some time with Mathematica. Try reading this Q&A http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193